# Resources for informatics olympiads and acm icpc competitions?

Tags: books

Recently I am learning c++ programming language. I wanted to know some resources where I can get problems and theories related to acm icpc competition and informatics olympiads . Also can anyone tell me the specific contests that I should take in the websites like hackerrank, codechef to prepare for the contests. Thank you.